# Pegar valor string de um txt

Tags: java, string

Tenho em um txt que é espelho de uma impressora fiscal, gostaria de pegar o número do COO correspondente apenas da REDUÇÃO Z,
no exemplo a baixo gostaria de pegar apenas o valor 031717.

```
02/01/2014 11:50:06                   COO:031717

         REDUÇÃO Z       
MOVIMENTO DO DIA: 01/01/2014

02/01/2014 11:50:06                   COO:031718

         LEITURA X       
MOVIMENTO DO DIA: 01/01/2014
```

No meu Código eu consigo pegar todos os COO e colocar em outro arquivo, mas gostaria de pegar apenas o da Redução Z.

Segue trecho do código:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arquivo.txt"));
        String linha;
        while ((linha = br.readLine())!=null) {
            String texto="";
            if (linha.contains("COO:")) {
                texto = linha.substring(linha.length()-6, linha.length());
                FileWriter escrever = new FileWriter(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date())+".txt", true);
                escrever.append(texto+"\n");
                escrever.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Depois do C00, a próxima palavra é sempre o termo associado (REDUÇÃO Z, LEITURA X, ...)?

Comment: Sim, mas em linha diferente

Answer (score 0):

Se sempre for LEITURA ou REDUCAO, ao passar pelo COO crie um objeto que tenha dois campos, COO e tipo. Ai você guarda o COO e o tipo e guarda esse objeto numa lista. No final você vai ter uma lista de objetos já processados, então é só filtrar esses objetos os que tem REDUCAO ou LEITURA, conforme o que você precisar.